# iPhone StoreKit development: Can't create a test user?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, storekit

I'm trying to get up to speed on how to develop an in-app store using the new 3.0 SDK... but I'm a bit stuck in that I don't seem to be able to create a test account.  The iTunes Connect FAQ states "To create test users for your sandbox environment, go to the Manage Users section of iTunes Connect and select In App Purchase Test User. Your test users will not have iTunes Connect access. They will just have access to the sandbox environment."

...but when I go to that Manage Users section, there's no mention of any sort of "In App Purschase Test User" or how to make one.  Did I miss doing something to enable that?

There is another section of that same FAQ that seems to suggest I need to have a paid app in the store first?  Is that the reason I can't even use the test environment?

Answer (score 1):

Having the same issue and here's what i did to get it working:

- login to http://developer.apple.com/iphone
- CLick "My Profile", next to "Hi, your name"
- Leave first page, click continue
- Where its says "Please select the primary category for your application(s)", make sure you tick second option "Commercial Applications"
- hit continue
- then go to itunes connect
- click "Contracts, Tax, & Banking Information"
- you will find a new "Paid Application" contract
- tick the box next to it and add it
- follow the prompts, no need to submit any Tax info for your testing
- now go to itunes connect - Manage Users
  and there you have it, both options "Itunes Connect User" and "In App Purchase User" are now available.

Answer (score 0):

Have you signed up for the 3.0 beta access? If not, that may be why you can't see the information. For me, when I log into iTunes Connect and click on Manage Users, it asks for me to select a user type. I have to choose either "In App Purchase Test User" and "iTunes Connect User"

Comment: Yeah, I've definitely signed up for it.  I have the 3.0 GM Seed releases of the SDK and I have the corresponding OS on my iPod.

Comment: When I click on Manage Users I go directly to a list of users and can only "Add New User", edit one of my existing users, or cancel.  I went through adding a new user just before I posted originally and it never asked me about choosing a user type.  
The closest thing thing I saw was when it asked me what 'Role' the user should have, but that's very different.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the answer then. You should probably try to contact Apple to see if they can enable whatever needs to be enabled in your account.

Comment: I've since asked apple's developer support about it, but I'm still waiting to hear back from them.

Comment: I did finally hear back from apple, but they weren't much help. They just said to read the program portal user guide. I tried looking through that but haven't really found the answer yet. I did discover that I need to make sure the App ID is a specific one (one that doesn't end in a '*') and that the Team Agent has enabled it to use In App Purchases. Doing that still hasn't allowed me to create a test user, however.